# How can I do ListSelectionListener from Object's list?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listselectionlistener

I have a task to do using `ListSelectionListener`. I need to output there, an `ArrayList` with class objects.

```
public class CityBaseLandingSite {
    public String city;
    public String country;
    public boolean possibleLanding;

    public CityBaseLandingSite(String city, String country, boolean possibleLanding) {
        super(city, country);
        this.city = city;
        this.country = country;
        this.possibleLanding = possibleLanding;
    }
 }
```

---

```
public class JFrameDemo extends JFrame {

JLabel label = new JLabel();
public JFrameDemo(String title) throws HeadlessException
{
    super(title);
    setBounds(100, 100, 200, 200);
    Container ControlHost = getContentPane();
    ControlHost.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    ArrayList<CityBaseLandingSite> citiesArrayList = new ArrayList<CityBaseLandingSite>();
    citiesArrayList.add(new CityBaseLandingSite("New York", "USA", true));
    citiesArrayList.add(new CityBaseLandingSite("Kyiv", "Ukraine", true));
    citiesArrayList.add(new CityBaseLandingSite("Tel-Aviv", "Israel", false));

    JList ListCities = new JList(citiesArrayList.toArray());

    ListCities.setVisibleRowCount(4);

    JScrollPane jcp = new JScrollPane(ListCities);
    ControlHost.add(jcp);
    ControlHost.add(label);

    ListCities.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            Object SelectedCity =  ListCities.getSelectedValue();
            label.setText(SelectedCity.toString());
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrameDemo jFrameDemo = new JFrameDemo("City");
    jFrameDemo.setSize(500, 500);
    //fixed sizes
    jFrameDemo.setResizable(false);
        jFrameDemo.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5T8G.png]

Field of City need in `JList` **(only name city)**, cities data need be in label.

Comment: So . . where does the code attempt to implement a `ListSelectionListener`? Where are you stuck? Note that SO is a Q&A site rather than a 'complete my project' site.

Comment: 1) Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. 2) I'm not sure I understand the question but I guess you cast the selected value from the list to a CityBaseLandingSite. Then you need to add getter methods to the class to you can access the city value.

Comment: *"Field of City need in JList (only name city), cities data need be in label"* - Sounds like you need to look at [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer)